# работаю с discord python. хочу чтобы бот не считал свою собственную реакцию, а только людей. Как сделать так, чтобы бот игнорировал свои реакции?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

У меня есть кусок кода. Весь код я давать не буду:

```
@bot.command()
async def меню(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    print(author, 'использовал команду меню')
    await ctx.send('Выберите вкладку: :hut: - ваш город')
    @bot.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        msg = await ctx.send('работает!')
        await msg.add_reactions('\U0001F6D6')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'Выберите вкладку: :hut: - ваш город':
        await message.add_reaction('\U0001F6D6')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

В другом куске кода он ставит на своё же сообщение 'Выберите вкладку:' реакцию :hut:
Я хочу, чтобы когда я тоже поставил реакцию он написал 'работает!'. Но он пишет 'работает!' когда сам ставит реакцию на своё же сообщение. Как сделать так, чтобы бот игнорировал свои реакции?

Comment: Чтобы бот воспринимал обработчик реакций, его нужно создать в общем коде, а не внутри функции `меню`. Ну, а далее просто проверяйте в функции `on_raw_reaction_add`, если `payload.user_id == bot.user.id`, то выполняйте возврат (`return`), чтобы функция не выполнялась далее

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте ещё проще.

```
msg = await ctx.send('работает!')

await msg.add_reactions('✅')
await msg.add_reactions('❌')
```

Бот, когда пишет своё сообщение сразу ставит реакцию и не реагирует на неё. По крайней мере, раньше так и было.
Показал на примере ✅, ❌ у вас эмодзи будут свои.

Comment: больше кода:
$bot.command()
async def меню(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    print(author, 'использовал команду меню')
    await ctx.send('Выберите вкладку: :hut: - ваш город')
    $bot.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        msg = await ctx.send('работает!')
        await msg.add_reactions('\U0001F6D6')
$bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'Выберите вкладку: :hut: - ваш город':
        await message.add_reaction('\U0001F6D6')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
Всё равно сам на своё реагирует!(
PS $=собака;

Comment: Нажмите править под своим сообщением, не нужно сюда код кидать, ничего не понятно

Comment: добавил новый кусок кода. Помогите(

Comment: Что это за реакции? \U0001F6D6
Нужно указать именно смайл, как в примере сверху.

Comment: вы заблуждаетесь, мой друг. Я нашёл этот код на сайте кодов смайлов, и бот на своё сообщение ставит тот смайл, что мне нужен. Я уверен, что это правильно. И да, поя ошибка очевидно в тупом коде. В общем, я ждал, что этот фрагмент сделают за меня(